# PHP : Change Array structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a set of array like this from selecting database, where [0] in the table is ID,  [1] is Item, and [2] is Type :

```
Array
(
    [0] => LO001
    [1] => Fork
    [2] => A
)
Array
(
    [0] => LO002
    [1] => Spoon
    [2] => B
)
```

But i want it to be like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => LO001
          [1] => Fork
          [2] => A
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
          [0] => LO002
          [1] => Spoon
          [2] => B
        )
)
```

*edit, code for select data from DB, $selected is a set of an array from checkbox form result. :

```
$query = "SELECT ID, name, type FROM location WHERE loc_id = '$selected'";
    $sqlcb = mysql_query($query);
    $ccb = array();
    while($ccb= mysql_fetch_array($sqlcb)) {
        print_r($ccb);
}
```

$selected array structure example (this array could be change based on user input from checkbox form.

```
 Array
 (
   [0] => LO001
   [1] => LO002
)
```

Comment: $new_array = ""; foreach($your_array as $ar){$new_array[] = $ar;} print_r($new_array);

Comment: Show us the code fetching the array from database. Otherwise, the question is ambiguous. There are millions of ways to construct such kind of array.

Comment: Where's the php code ?

Comment: @PedroLobito edited.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov edited

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
while($ccb= mysql_fetch_array($sqlcb)) {
     $finalArray[] = $ccb;
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

---

Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: it works, but it appears new problem like this : `Array
(
    [0] => LO001
    [1] => Fork
    [2] => A
) Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => LO001
          [1] => Fork
          [2] => A
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
          [0] => LO002
          [1] => Spoon
          [2] => B
        )
)`

Comment: I cannot test your code, but you can try removing `$finalArray = array();`

Comment: Ok. Thank you for reponding my question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new array like:

```
$arr1 =  array('LO001','Fork','A');
$arr2 =  array('LO002','Spoon','B');

$newArr = array();
$newArr[] = $arr1;
$newArr[] = $arr2;
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => LO001
            [1] => Fork
            [2] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => LO002
            [1] => Spoon
            [2] => B
        )

)
```

Comment: you have obtained the same array. Nothing has changed

Comment: he has trouble constructing the array by fetching data from a database. I think he is able to replicate the output of `print_r`.